# How to compare strings with placeholders in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Say you have a string such as this:

```
"ERROR: Error Number %d, Error Location 0x%x, found exception"
```

Suppose you write a program to search a text file looking for this exact string but you don't care about the placeholders `%d`, `%x`, but you want to make sure you match the string correctly.  how would you go about doing it?

One might think why not just compare the substring: `"ERROR: Error Number"` ..., well suppose then that there are other strings in the text file with the same starting substring `"ERROR: Error Number"`, but you don't want to capture those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, used [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

You have to convert your format into a RegEx:

- first, escape the non-alphanumeric characters;
- replace each format (e.g.: `%d`) by a corresponding RegEx, (e.g.: `\d+`);
- add the `^` and `$` operators to ensure you have exact match;
- compile the RegEx for optimisation;
- use the `match`, `findall`, etc.

Here is an example:

```
import re

my_format = "ERROR: Error Number %d, Error Location 0x%x, found exception"

# Escape all non-alphanumeric characters in pattern
my_regex = re.escape(my_format)

# Mapping: pattern => regex
mapping = [(r"\%d", r"\d+"),
           (r"\%x", r"[0-9a-f]+")]

# Substitute each pattern by regex
for pattern, regex in mapping:
    my_regex = my_regex.replace(pattern, regex)

# Add begin/end operator for exact match
my_regex = "^" + my_regex + "$"
print(my_regex)

# Compile the RegEx, extract the 'match' function
match_my_regex = re.compile(my_regex, re.DOTALL).match

samples = ["789",
           "ERROR: Error Number 123, Error Location 0xaf, found exception",
           "ERROR: Error Number 456, Error Location 0xa0, found exception",
           "Got ERROR: Error Number 123, Error Location 0xaf, found exception"]

for sample in samples:
    print("{0}: match => {1}".format(sample, match_my_regex(sample) is not None))
```

You will obtain:

```
789: match => False
ERROR: Error Number 123, Error Location 0xaf, found exception: match => True
ERROR: Error Number 456, Error Location 0xa0, found exception: match => True
Got ERROR: Error Number 123, Error Location 0xaf, found exception: match => False
```

Comment: What happens when I have a string with widths specified such as: 0x%08x where the hex number is padded by 8 characters.  What would the regex expression need to be in order to handle this width?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression.
In your case, you would want to use something like:

http://pythex.org/?regex=ERROR%3A%5CsError%5CsNumber%5Cs(%5Cd%2B)%2C%5CsError%5CsLocation%5Cs0x(%5Cd%2B)%2C%5Csfound%5Csexception&test_string=ERROR%3A%20Error%20Number%2032%2C%20Error%20Location%200x420%2C%20found%20exception&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Example:

```
import re
arr = ['testing', 'ERROR: Error Number 32, Error Location 0x420, found exception', 'test']
regex = re.compile('ERROR:\sError\sNumber\s(\d+),\sError\sLocation\s0x(\d+),\sfound\sexception')
for string in arr:
    if re.match(regex, string):
        print(string)
```